# Destroying city's walls stops their defensive bombard?

Tags: civilization-6

I am assaulting a city. The city bombarded my catapult almost to death. I had moved 3 in.

The next turn or two later, I noticed the city is not bombarding me anymore.

Does destroying city's walls stop their defensive bombard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroying a city centre's walls neutralises the bombard ability. The same for the encampment. Both are mutually  exclusive.

Walls cannot be repaired if they have been damaged in the last 3 turns.
[Source](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/civ-6-guide-how-siege-cities-and-conquer-your-enemies-564550)

I had yet to experience or confirm if the same 3 turn barrier to repairing is also for the encampment.